# setting long integer's access field from c#

Tags: c#, dao, recordset

I am using DAO's recordset to fill up tables from c# that's because I 'am inserting millions of records and using DAO is really fast, faster than ADO.Net, but I got this problem in one table I have a "long integer" field, and I can't set a value (my long number is 296401700001786) to it, an error says Message = "Not enough memory to continue running the program."

```
    long xx=296401700001786;  
    rs.Fields["myField"].Value = xx;
```

where myField  is a long integer in access

thanks for any help

Comment: Is it an option to run a SQL `UPDATE` to modify the field?

Comment: ADO is old and is probably using 32 bits for long and your number is 52 bits.  You can use double which will loose precision or update your ado driver to 64 bits.